# Remove duplicate records from query of 2 tables

Tags: sql

I have the following 2 table:

Table 1 : invoices 
invoiceID  clientName
| 1            | Tony
| 2            | Ludwig
| 3            | Ralph

Table 2 : invoice_items
invoiceID  itemDescription
| 1            | Flat monitor LED etc...
| 1            | HP Printer Inkjet etc...
| 2            | Laptop wahtever etc...

I'm trying to query only the invoices from Table "invoices", but allow the user the search the item descriptions.

I have written

```
$query = "SELECT i.*, ii.invoiceID, ii.itemDescription from invoices i, invoice_items ii, WHERE ii.itemDescription like "%'.$_GET["s"].'%" AND i.invoiceID = ii.invoiceID";
```

but this will results in duplicates. any ideas ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want you could call distinct  .. but in this case you must select the column  you need explicitally

```
$query = "SELECT distinct i.col1, i.col2, i.col3, ii.invoiceID, ii.itemDescription 
      from invoices i, invoice_items ii, 
      WHERE ii.itemDescription like "%'.$_GET["s"].'%" 
      AND i.invoiceID = ii.invoiceID";
```

yyou can obtaion distinct  this way  (if you don't need descriptio in your result)

```
$query = "SELECT distinct i.col1, i.col2, i.col3
      from invoices i, invoice_items ii, 
      WHERE ii.itemDescription like "%'.$_GET["s"].'%" 
      AND i.invoiceID = ii.invoiceID";
```

Comment: this could be only if the itemDescription is not unique ..    .. then you don'have duplicated row .. but some column are the same ..

Comment: @LudwigArcache DISTINCT will work but this answer needs to be updated to remove ii.itemDescription from the SELECT list.  If it remains DISTINCT will not give you distinct invoice columns because they are from the invoice_item table

Comment: @scaisEdge thanks for your help, I'm having duplicate records with or without search entry.

Comment: @LudwigArcache  show me the result you obtain and the result you want .. update your question ..

Comment: @Matt thanks, so if I remove ii.itemDescription from the SELECT, how can I use it ? can you give me a small example ?

Comment: @LudwigArcache   . anyway i have update the answer witha suggestion hope is useful

Comment: $query = "SELECT distinct i.invoiceID, i.clientName, ii.invoiceID, ii.itemDescription 
      from invoices i, invoice_items ii, 
      WHERE ii.itemDescription like "%'.$_GET["s"].'%" 
      AND i.invoiceID = ii.invoiceID";

Comment: Thank you @scaisEdge, it worked by removing ii.itemDescription from SELECT. and it is still useful in WHERE ii.itemDescription like "%'.$_GET["s"].'%"

Comment: @LudwigArcache   It took a moment to realize you needed a description for the query but not for the result .. .. .. well. If my answer is that you are looking for please mark it as accepted ..